# zeppelin spark saveAsTextFile

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

What happened if I run rdd.saveAsTextFile() on zeppelin note book?

I can't find the saved file, and theree is no error happened, showed as:

[image: result picture]

Comment: I am unsure what you are asking about...

Comment: I want to know where the urlText file is in. It should be saved in some location, I open the zeppelin on my own computer with a given name and a password